# Argument 'CommentsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope

I'm new to Angular and I'm just following a tutorial.
I've got this error and can't understand why.

**Argument 'CommentsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined**

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>tuto</title>
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
            {{comment.name}}
            {{comment.comment}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function CommentsCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.comments = [
           {
             "name": "Terra",
             "comment": "Eu reprehenderit id excepteur do commodo ad do. Amet occaecat in ex "
           },
           // other comments ...
        ]
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Angular 1.3.x you cant define global controllers by defualt

use .`controller()`

```
angular.module('myModule')
.controller('CommentsCtrl'.function CommentsCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.comments = [
           {
             "name": "Terra",
             "comment": "Eu reprehenderit  "
           },
           // other comments ...
        ]
    })
```

or set global controller option

```
angular.module('myModule').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

in html

```
 <body ng-app="myModule">
```